# Build Expo Go application alternative

Tags: react-native, expo

I am curious about which API and approaches I can use to build the core functionality of the Expo GO application:

1. Download js bundle within the app
2. Run this JS bundle instead of bundled with the app
3. If restarting the application start with the prebuilt bundle instead of the downloaded
4. Need to support Hermes (separate question about building JS bundle using Hermes CLI)

I tried to use https://github.com/killserver/react-native-dynamic-bundle-restore but his library looks outdated, it replaces the default bundle and looks like it doesn't support Hermes.